# Marking query in particular case

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the relationship follow as:

```
class Question(models.Model):
  qid = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
  content = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Answer(models.Model):
  answerid = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
  content = models.CharField(max_length=128)
  question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
```

I want to find the questions, which have the answer. How can I do it?
Please help me to solve this problem.
Thank you so much.

Comment: It might be helpful to go back to your past questions and accept some answers if you want to continue to receive help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to find all the questions that have answers:

```
Question.objects.filter(answer__isnull=False).distinct()
```